# Google home skill not working for multiple users

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing a Google Home Action using Action SDK in node.js, where user can order food. 
It works fine for one user, but when I add multiple users in Alpha testing, the conversation is linked for every user.

For eg:

```
    User 1: Ok, google talk to food app
    Response: Welcome, what would you like to order?
    User 1: I want to order pizza
    Response: What toppings you would like?
    /*---- meanwhile if user 2 tries to use the app -----*/
    User 2: Ok, google talk to food app
    Response: What toppings you would like?
```

When user 2 comes up, instead of starting from beginning it will continue the conversation that was going on for User 1.
This is a very odd problem and I am unsure how to tackle this in node.js.

Specifics:
Language: Node.js
Deployed the Google Home Action in Alpha testing.

Comment: Please add more details. At the very least a question should have a minimal set of code to allow us to reproduce the issue, in addition to including information on what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Hi David, I can't write the code here as it is confidential, but I am basically trying to understand session management in nodejs app based on the conversation id received from google home.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is impossible to know what is going on.

Most likely is that you are storing the session state in variables in your code, rather than storing the state in the session storage object. Your webhook may get fulfillment calls from multiple sessions, so you can't store anything about any of these sessions locally, but must restore them each time.